# How to recursively delete items from table?

Tags: mysql, recursion, cascading-deletes

I've a MySQL table "folders":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `folders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `folder_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I don't use integer IDs, only keys (alphanumeric hashes, which I've replaced with words to make things more clear). So, `folder_key` & `parent_key` are SHA-1 hashes (in my real application).

```
INSERT INTO `folders` (`id`, `folder_key`, `parent_key`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'sun', 'root', '1'),
(2, 'moon', 'sun', '1.1'),
(3, 'jupiter', 'moon', '1.1.1'),
(4, 'mars', 'root', '2');
```

As you can see the first item has a parent_key too, it's a root key.

The test case: 
If I wish to delete an item with `folder_key` === `moon` (1.1), it should also delete its children element(s), in this case it's an item with `folder_key` === `jupiter` (1.1.1) and so on...

Let say I wish to delete multiple items, so I do:

`DELETE from folders WHERE folder_key IN('moon', 'mars');`
After execution, the table should have only one item with `folder_key` === `sun`

So, the question is: 
**How to delete items from that table having one or more folder_keys (recursively) with MySQL triggers, ON DELETE CASCADE or ... ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this model it is imposibble

1. Instead of root use NULL , so you can use InnoDB Foreign Key + Cascade Delete.
2. Instead of using string parent_key, use id ( eg. sun = 1, moon = 2 )

Other way is to change data model, so you can easly select any descendands of element - see this for example http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Answer (score 3):

You can add a FOREIGN KEY on `folders` with CASCADE option for DELETE:

```
ALTER TABLE `folders` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_folder_parent` FOREIGN KEY `FK_folder_parent` (`parent_key`)
REFERENCES `folders` (`folder_key`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: What is the error? Bad syntax or do you have values that doesn't match? I see you that the `parent_key` is NOT NULL? You should make it NULL to root folders, right?

Comment: thank you very much. I solved my problem by changing the model.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing the "Parent key" value store their id

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `folders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `folder_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
foreign key(`parent_key`) on delete cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Naveen

you should use the same datatypes when creating a cascade delete constraint. Now you have an unsigned int and a signed int.