# SQL Tree Delete by Parent ID

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a DB (Tree) that looks like this:

[image]

So when I delete a questions I want to delete the whole tree linked to that questions but I don't know how to do this :(. Do you have any ideas?

I have this query but it deletes only the question and the questions linked to that question but it stops there.

```
DELETE FROM support_faq WHERE id=".$id_intrebare." OR parinte=".$id_intrebare
```

Comment: is there "on delete cascade" applied to table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? Sounds like you need a recursive query.

Comment: MySQL. So how can I do that? :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursively delete items from table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259448/how-to-recursively-delete-items-from-table)

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive queries. You will need to write a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **FOREIGN key** with **ON DELETE CASCADE** option

for example

> ALTER TABLE ChildTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (columnName_c) REFERENCES
>   ParentTable(columnName_p) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: So first of all, you said that I must create 2 tables from my table?
I have ID,TYPE,PARINTE(PARRENT) AND TEXT.

Comment: @user3175636  you have only one table? if yes than use sub-query for achieving your result.

Comment: I can't use sub-query because I don't know what questions I have linked to my deleted question.

Comment: After doing this my queries(DELETE, INSERT) doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one table with loosely coupled parent and child relationship. You can write a procedure to delete your record recursively.

1. Please follow the link to get to know how to write procedure in mysql
2. Also it will let you know how you can use the loop

[LINK](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/12/mysql-how-to-write-loop-in-mysql/)